# Query Cosmos DB to get a list of different derived types using the .Net SDK Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We have an interface and a base class with multiple derived types.

```
public interface IEvent
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    string Type { get; }
}

public abstract class EventBase: IEvent
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public abstract string Type { get; }
}

public class UserCreated : EventBase
{
    public override string Type { get; } = typeof(UserCreated).AssemblyQualifiedName;
}

public class UserUpdated : EventBase
{
    public override string Type { get; } = typeof(UserUpdated).AssemblyQualifiedName;
}
```

We are storing these events of different derived types in the same container in Cosmos DB using v3 of .Net SDK `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos`. We then want to read all the events and have them deserialized to the correct type.

```
public class CosmosDbTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task TestFetchingDerivedTypes()
    {
        var endpoint = "";
        var authKey = "";
        var databaseId ="";
        var containerId="";

        var client = new CosmosClient(endpoint, authKey);

        var container = client.GetContainer(databaseId, containerId);

        await container.CreateItemAsync(new UserCreated{ Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
        await container.CreateItemAsync(new UserUpdated{ Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });

        var queryable = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<IEvent>();

        var query = queryable.ToFeedIterator();
        var list = new List<IEvent>();

        while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            list.AddRange(await query.ReadNextAsync());
        }

        Assert.NotEmpty(list);
    }
}
```

Doesn't seem to be any option to tell `GetItemLinqQueryable` how to handle types. Is there any other method or approach to support multiple derived types in one query?

It's ok to put the events in some kind of wrapper entity if that would help, but they aren't allowed to be stored as an serialized sting inside a property.

Comment: Are you using a custom `CosmosSerializer`?

Comment: No, but your question helped me find this blog https://thomaslevesque.com/2019/10/15/handling-type-hierarchies-in-cosmos-db-part-2/ that helped me come up with a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from Stephen Clearly pointed me in the right direction and with the help of this blog https://thomaslevesque.com/2019/10/15/handling-type-hierarchies-in-cosmos-db-part-2/ I ended up with a solution similar to the following example were we have a custom `CosmosSerializer` that uses a custom `JsonConverter` that reads the Type property.

```
public interface IEvent
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("$type")]
    string Type { get; }
}

public abstract class EventBase: IEvent
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Type => GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;
}

public class UserCreated : EventBase
{
}

public class UserUpdated : EventBase
{
}
```

`EventJsonConverter` reads the `Type` property.

```
public class EventJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    // This converter handles only deserialization, not serialization.
    public override bool CanRead => true;
    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        // Only if the target type is the abstract base class
        return objectType == typeof(IEvent);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // First, just read the JSON as a JObject
        var obj = JObject.Load(reader);

        // Then look at the $type property:
        var typeName = obj["$type"]?.Value<string>();

        return typeName == null ? null : obj.ToObject(Type.GetType(typeName), serializer);

    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("This converter handles only deserialization, not serialization.");
    }
}
```

The `NewtonsoftJsonCosmosSerializer` takes a `JsonSerializerSettings` that it uses for serialization.

```
public class NewtonsoftJsonCosmosSerializer : CosmosSerializer
{
    private static readonly Encoding DefaultEncoding = new UTF8Encoding(false, true);

    private readonly JsonSerializer _serializer;

    public NewtonsoftJsonCosmosSerializer(JsonSerializerSettings settings)
    {
        _serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);
    }

    public override T FromStream<T>(Stream stream)
    {
        if (typeof(Stream).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
        {
            return (T)(object)stream;
        }

        using var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        using var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr);

        return _serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonTextReader);
    }

    public override Stream ToStream<T>(T input)
    {
        var streamPayload = new MemoryStream();
        using var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(streamPayload, encoding: DefaultEncoding, bufferSize: 1024, leaveOpen: true);
        using JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(streamWriter);

        writer.Formatting = _serializer.Formatting;
        _serializer.Serialize(writer, input);
        writer.Flush();
        streamWriter.Flush();

        streamPayload.Position = 0;
        return streamPayload;
    }
}
```

The CosmosClient is now created with our own `NewtonsoftJsonCosmosSerializer` and `EventJsonConverter`.

```
public class CosmosDbTests
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task TestFetchingDerivedTypes()
    {
        var endpoint = "";
        var authKey = "";
        var databaseId ="";
        var containerId="";

        var client = new CosmosClient(endpoint, authKey, new CosmosClientOptions
        {
            Serializer = new NewtonsoftJsonCosmosSerializer(new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                Converters = { new EventJsonConverter() }
            })
        });

        var container = client.GetContainer(databaseId, containerId);

        await container.CreateItemAsync(new UserCreated{ Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
        await container.CreateItemAsync(new UserUpdated{ Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });

        var queryable = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<IEvent>();

        var query = queryable.ToFeedIterator();
        var list = new List<IEvent>();

        while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            list.AddRange(await query.ReadNextAsync());
        }

        Assert.NotEmpty(list);
    }
}
```